# how do I add a page link in the ok button of Swal in Angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, sweetalert

This is my **html file**

```
<button (click)="pay()">Add to Cart</button>
```

This is my **ts file**

```
pay(){
    Swal.fire(
      `Congratulations!!`,
      `<h3>The item has been added to the cart!!<h3>`,
      'success');
  }
```

So, when I click on the **OK**(which in here is success), I want user to redirect to the Cart Page of the site. How do I add a link?

Comment: https://sweetalert.js.org/docs/#content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
pay(){
    Swal.fire(
      `Congratulations!!`,
      `<h3>The item has been added to the cart!!<h3>`,
      'success').then(() => {
            this.router.navigate(['/yourCartPage']);
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just make use of JavaScript promises. Put the then method after swal function. We do not need to use timer features. For example:

```
  swal({
      title: 'Request Delivered',
      text: 'You can continue with your search.',
      type: 'success'
    }).then(function() {
        window.location = "redirectURL";
    })
```

Thank you

Comment: this is giving me error on window.location as: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Location'.ts(2322)
(property) location: Location.